# INFO: {textract, us-east-1} was not found in region metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, text-extraction

INFO: {textract, us-east-1} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.

Answer (score 0):

If we used "AmazonTextractClientBuilder.defaultClient()" For the AmazonTextract client, Textract default added or elase we can set own endpoint using standard().withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endPoint,region)). This is not any error. Just information given to the user. The endpoint for the textract is "https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".